# How to make an event logger loop work with other loop for arduino uno?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm fairly new to this but I've been researching for a while now and no conclusive answer.

**How do I make a loop that constantly outputs Serial.println of changes in digitalWrite.**

Background info; I am making a traffic light with buttons and pedestrian lights too. I have a sequence for when one of the buttons is pressed but I need a separate loop that outputs changes in lights- which lights are on or which button is pressed. Essentially an event logger that loops throughout the entire script constantly.

**
Sorry, I should have specified; when the button is clicked it goes through a whole sequence, its blocking code. More specifically it's blocking the loop i have for the event logger. How do I work them side-by-side? Whatever I try, it's either the light sequence works or the event logger works but never together. My research indicated that I should use the millis function but I don't know how to implement it.

```
const int red = 8;
const int yellow = 2;
const int green = 3;

const int p_red = 5;
const int p_green = 6;

const int button1 = 4; 
const int button2 = 7;

const int state1 = digitalRead(button1);
const int state2 = digitalRead(button2);

unsigned long waitTime = 500;

void setup() {
  
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, INPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
        // turn on the default lights (traffic green and pedestrian red)
  digitalWrite(green, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(p_red, HIGH); 
    
  if(millis() >= waitTime)  {
    Serial.print("state: ");
    Serial.println(state1);
    //delay(1000);
  }

   if(state1 || state2 == HIGH) {
    // State 1  // ID Sequence: 3, 5, 6, 1, 5, 2, 10, 
    digitalWrite(green, HIGH);   
    digitalWrite(p_red, HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(green, LOW);   
    // State 2
    digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);
    delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
    // State 3
    digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
    delay(6000);
    digitalWrite(p_red, LOW);
    // State 4
    digitalWrite(p_green, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(p_green, LOW);
    // State 5 - Flashing red v 5 cycles (200ms)
    for (int x=0+1; x<5; x++) {
    digitalWrite(p_red, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(p_red, LOW);
    delay(200);
    } // State 6
    digitalWrite(red, HIGH);   
    digitalWrite(p_red, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    // State 7
    digitalWrite(red, LOW);
    digitalWrite(green, HIGH);   
    digitalWrite(p_red, HIGH);
    delay(10000);
    // State 8
    digitalWrite(green, HIGH);   
    digitalWrite(p_red, HIGH);
    delay(8000);
    }
}
```

the problem with this current code is the if statement for the lights not working

Comment: You can do it the normal way, by writing a loop and calling `Serial.println`. Did you try that? What went wrong? Please [edit] your question to add more details about the problem you're facing with the code. What did your research show? What part(s) were inconclusive?

Comment: @CodyGray Sorry, I should have specified; when the button is clicked it goes through a whole sequence, its blocking code. More specifically it's blocking the loop i have for the event logger. How do I work them side-by-side? Whatever I try, it's either the light sequence works or the event logger works but never together.
My research indicated that I should use the millis function but I don't know how to implement it.